# Three.js overlapping transparent PNG textures have black backgrounds

Tags: three.js, transparency

(Ignore the grid)

[image: clouds]

I have many planes with a Three.MeshBasicMaterial on each one, and the map is a transparent PNG cloud image.

As you can see in the above image, **they are showing black backgrounds when overlapping with the rest of the scene.** Strangely, when they overlap with themselves, you can see they blend and are transparent (look at the outer red clouds blending with the inner pink clouds).

- I've verified the PNG images are actually transparent.
- As mentioned, they're on a MeshBasicMaterial, with transparency set to true, and the map is a cloud image with anisotropy set to 16.
- I have not manually set the blend mode on the materials

Anything obvious I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably specific to my own implementation - but in case it helps anyone else: I discovered the clouds only had black backgrounds when overlapping with the background skybox. The skybox materials had transparent: true, set on them, even though they aren't transparent. Removing the transparency setting from the background materials fixed the issue.